# what is basically happening in a php page

Tags: php, server-side

Let us consider the following html :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="submit.php">
    <input name="name" placeholder="Enter your name">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
```

Now to my understanding this code passes a list of arguments to a the php file which is mentioned in the action attribute of the method .

I understand that the code file is in the server system .

Now let us consider the code for submit.php as follow :

```
<?php 
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    Hello <?php echo $name;?>
</body>
</html>
```

These codes are taken from an answer to my last question .

Now after the submit button is clicked . The client requests for a new page from the server .

I wanted to know what exactly is happening here .  Does the server sends this code file to the browser and the php code is executed in the browser or submit.php , generates an html file according to the php code in it and that html file is sent to the client ?

Where is the code getting executed in the browser or in the server . With what I have read till now gives a feel that the code is being executed in the server but to be just sure .

Further , if the case is like the latter , i.e., the inputs are sent to server and the server based on the php code generates an html file that is sent back to the browser , then isn't it a bit inefficient in sending requests the server even for smaller changes ?

So what exactly is happening and where is the code getting executed ?

Comment: For one thing, if someone accesses that submit.php file directly, it will throw off undefined index/variable notices. Best you use `isset()` and/or `empty()`. Besides that, the question is too broad, IMHO.

Comment: php code is executed before thge page is sent to the browser, then on the server. The php interpreter read the code and prepares the html that is sent to the browser where it is interpreted and rendered.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP source is on the server and remains there. It is executed there, and the result (which is typically HTML, but can be anything else too), is sent as a response to the browser, so you got that right.

The advantage is that the PHP code itself is hidden to to user, and it can do advanced stuff like accessing files and databases which are hidden, and usually unaccessible directly for your website visitor.

The PHP code may be accidentally exposed when PHP is not set up properly. In that case, the code won't run but may be returned as plain text by accident. If you ever see PHP code in your browser, it's almost certainly due to an incorrect server set-up.

Even a small change should usually be done by the server. Theoretically it's inefficient to do those requests all the time, but in reality a request is not a big deal. If you *only* want to update the page itself, without doing anything special to the server, you could use JavaScript which can run in the browser as part of your page, and which can manipulate the loaded HTML document.

Comment: `Normally it is executed there` (on the server). How does the code run on the browser. I have never heard of that.

Comment: I rephrased that.

Comment: @GolezTrol : So , is there anything that is done to prevent the repetitive process of request sending ?

Comment: It depends on what the script is doing. Some things have to happen on a server, because, for instance, you need info from a database or need to persist data. If it's just about changing the UI, you could do all that in the browser itself using JavaScript. Hiding data is also a factor here. For instance, you could simply write a minesweeper game in JavaScript which wouldn't need any requests to the server while playing. But that also means that the position of the mines is available in JavaScript, in the browser, making it accessible to the visitor.

Answer (score 1):

The whole process or execution life cycle can be explained in the following two steps:

**Step-1:**
Server-side PHP blocks enclosed in `<?php ?>` tags are executed and removed from the code base on the server on every request.

**Step-2:**
Client-side script and HTML tags left in step-1 are send for execution and display in the browser.

I hope the explanation is easily understandable now.

Comment: Nuamaan : Yes , quite clear . Just was doubting that because of  the inefficiency owing to the repetitive request sending .

Comment: I believe my answer can be marked as correct. Please let me know if you have any further question or needs more clarification.